# How to support 2 inch SCH80 PVC conduit on exterior brick wall?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a 2 inch SCH 80 PVC conduit for a 15 feet run on a brick veneer wall. The conduit exits main service panel at a knockout 45 inches from the ground, travels 11 feet horizontally, takes a 90 degree turn, runs for another 2 feet before terminating into a L-conduit-body. The other end of the conduit body enters the crawl space through a hole in the brick wall.

What is the best way to support this conduit on the wall? Can I use [metal strap hangers like these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-5-ACC-Conduit-and-Pipe-Hanger-67850/100139436)? My inspector has cleared me for using these, but wanted to check what you guys use for conduit that big.

Second, does NEC allow one conduit to go over another? The conduit in question will intersect a 1/2 inch EMT conduit run at a single point. The metal straps I linked above raise the conduit enough from the wall to create the needed clearance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the correct size hanger for the conduit size, it's made to work for that size conduit. So hardly surprising that your LAHJ approved it.

You will, of course, need suitable bolts and anchors to attach it to the wall.

You could also use 2-bolt strap hangers and make a minor bend with heat to pass over the EMT, with the PVC against the wall for the rest of its run.

Comment: I was planning to use tapcon screws. Is that acceptable?  Heating and bending the pipe is a little outside my experience. I wish they made an offset fitting at that size.

Comment: Bending PVC is easy, if you pay attention to what you are doing. The heat can be obtained via fancy expensive heating blankets you have no need for, boiling water, or (with great care not to **over** heat it) a hot air gun.

Answer (score 3):

The product page states:

> Secure and suspend 2 in. rigid and EMT conduits from **overhead** supports

I imagine that when installed on a wall they could eventually bend down a bit but highly doubtful they would outright break nor pull the screw out of the wall.

When in doubt just tighten up the spacing so instead of every 24", install one every 16" or whatever.

If that is the same product as [this](https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Conduit-Cable-Clamps/nVent-Caddy/CD5B/product.aspx?zpid=13230) then just take solace in knowing it's rated for 350 pounds.

---

The only negative about the product is that it's only zinc-plated so eventually it will rust.

Comment: Yeah, same type of product, only made by Halex. I was planning to install one every 12 inches taking bending into consideration.

Comment: @cryptic0 I assume a 12" run of 2" of conduit even when stuffed to the max will not touch the 350 pound rating =)